# What is this opening called?

Tags: opening, opening-traps

I would like to know what this opening is called, if someone has made a bad move, and who stands better.

Finally if this opening is played by grandmasters [here](https://www.pgnmentor.com/files.html).

[image]

Comment: 1. d4 d5 2. c4 Nf6 is already not so good, because white plays 3. cd Nxd4 4. e4 gaining a strong center with tempo.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo What is your `cd` ? I do not know the chess notation well.

Comment: Sorry - typos abound 3. cxd5 Nxd5.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Thank you for your explanation. What is good after 1.d4 d5 2.c4 ? How this openning is called?

Comment: Your choices are dxc4 (Queen's Gambit Accepted), c6 (Slav), e6 (Queen's Gambit Declined), or both c6 and e6 in either order (Semi-Slav).

Comment: Regarding bad moves, any online engine answers that. Amusingly, both castlings are declared inferior, but I hadn't needed one regarding the bad 9...Sh5 (which at least drops the Ph7) and 11...b6 (which loses a piece, but cashing in immediately with f3 and g4 isn't even the best continuation!)

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia, it is the [Marshall defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshall_Defense), played by Frank Marshall in the 1920s, until he gave it up after losing to Alekhine in 1925 at Baden Baden.

Answer (score 3):

1. d4 d5 2. c4 form the start of the Queen's Gambit family of openings. Black's reply ...Nf6 is weak enough to possibly not deserve a name (at least none comes to mind at the moment). Black's typical reply is either ...e6, heading towards the Orthodox Queen's Gambit Declined family tree, ...c6 leading to the Slav tree, or ... dxc4 and the Queen's Gambit Accepted. There are also other lines of varying degrees of respectability, but these are the main ones.

The text move (...Nf6) just begs white to take the d-pawn, and whether black recaptures with the knight and gets chased by e4 or recaptures with the queen and gets chased by Nc3, White gains a significant advantage. In the Chessbase Online DB, white scores around 80% in either line, which seems to me a good reason to stop thinking about Nf6 and try something sounder.

Comment: 2...Nf6 is usually called the Marshall defense.

Comment: It's way too early to assign a name. If White plays cd, then perhaps there's something with a name. But after ...Nf6 this could be Cambridge Springs, Tarrasch, Orthodox, Tartakover, Lasker, etc. In this case it's the White c5 move that steers us out of the variations. That c5 move seems ill-advised, but it's likely playable because Black's B is begging to be hit.

Comment: yet the named is usual in practice. The same way that 1.e4 c5 is generally called a Sicilian even though the game can still transpose to French, Panov or Kia for instance...

Answer (score 2):

You can click on the 'book' to view the opening , and can also select whether to check for this position in grandmaster games or in standard lichess games , and the moves usually next played.

If you click on the 'microscope' , you can access the computer analysis by scrolling down and clicking on 'request computer analysis' - which tells you about the blunders and best moves etc.

You can also start lichess server analysis for the moves by toggling the switch beside 'Stockfish 14+ NNUE' , which tells you the engine recommended moves at each point for each side .